# How to download file from google drive api with service account?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-ruby-client

Hello google hackers!

I am using Drive Service app and uploaded file successfully like this:

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2

upload_source = "/User/my_user_name/hacking.txt"
drive = Drive::DriveService.new
# Drive::AUTH_DRIVE is equal to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
drive.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default([Drive::AUTH_DRIVE])
file = drive.insert_file({title: 'hacking.txt'}, upload_source: upload_source)
```

`file` has a lot of properties, like this:
[download_url](https://doc-0o-4g-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ri17v16lk92ftgje59o3btsp1t9l50gs/lc66809dsim3v90dvkih5l6prd7qi6ck/1438934400000/14867473615787219362/14867473615787219362/0B4-SkuKSDBF-bFQ4Z0dWNEI2eFU?e=download&gd=true)

But when I try to open this `download_url` in browser it shows me blank screen.  Why I can't download it?

I guess, that may be there are permission problems? But the scope is correct, and uploading is successful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple - we cannot download it from `file` object, we must send another get request,  just download it like this:

```
drive.get_file(file.id, download_dest: '/tmp/my_file.txt')
```

Comment: `puts service.get_file(invoice.id, download_dest: "temp.pdf")` creates empty file for me.

Comment: I got it. Had to increase token permissions up to `Google::Apis::DriveV2::AUTH_DRIVE`

Comment: For V3 I had to use ``drive.export_file(<file id>, <mime type like 'application/pdf'>, download_dest: <my local path)``