# Download a file from Google Drive using google-api-ruby-client

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-ruby-client

I try to download files from a directory on Google Disk.

The code, mostly copied from [official quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ruby), works fine:

```
# ... code from official quickstart tutorial...

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize


# now the real deal
response = service.list_files(q: "'0ByJUN4GMe_2jODVJVVpmRE1VTDg' in parents and trashed != true",
                              page_size: 100,
                              fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)')
puts 'Files:'
puts 'No files found' if response.files.empty?
response.files.each do |file|
  puts "#{file.name} (#{file.id})"
  # content = service.get_file(file.id, download_dest: StringIO.new)
end
```

The output looks fine:

```
Files:
k.h264 (0B4D93ILRdf51Sk40UzBoYmZKMTQ)
output_file.h264 (0B4D93ILRdf51V1RGUDFIWFQ5cG8)
test.mp4 (0B4D93ILRdf51dWpoZWdBV3l4WjQ)
test2.mp4 (0B4D93ILRdf51ZmN4ZGlwZjBvR2M)
test3.mp4 (0B4D93ILRdf51ZXo0WnVfdVBjTlk)
12.mp4 (0ByJUN4GMe_2jRzEwS1FWTnVkX00)
01.mp4 (0ByJUN4GMe_2jSlRWVEw4a1gxa2s)
01.mp4 (0ByJUN4GMe_2jOFpPMW9YNjJuY2M)
```

But once I uncomment `content = service.get_file(file.id, download_dest: StringIO.new)`, I get a lot of errors:

```
Files:
k.h264 (0B4D93ILRdf51Sk40UzBoYmZKMTQ)
/Users/mvasin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.15/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:211:in `check_status': Invalid request (Google::Apis::ClientError)
[...lots of other 'from' stuff...]
from /Users/mvasin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.15/generated/google/apis/drive_v3/service.rb:772:in `get_file'
from quickstart.rb:56:in `block in <main>'
from quickstart.rb:54:in `each'
from quickstart.rb:54:in `<main>'
```

But that's the way it should work according to ruby section in ["download files" official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).

I also tried `content = service.get_file(file.id, download_dest: "/tmp/#{file.name}")`, but it failed with the same set of errors.

**UPDATE: Here are my findings.** If you start with [Google Drive API Ruby quick start tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ruby), and want make it download something,

1) change scope to not just let your script read meatadata, but read files contents as well:

`SCOPE = Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY`
to at least
`SCOPE = Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE_READONLY`

2) Filter out google docs files, because you can't download them this way, you have to convert them. To filer them:

2.1) Add `mime_type` to fileds set:

`response = service.list_files(page_size: 10, fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, mime_type)')`

2.2) and in the final loop where you print files' ids and names, put something like

`service.get_file(file.id, download_dest: "/your/path/#{file.name}") unless file.mime_type.include? "application/vnd.google-apps"`

Comment: Do you get the same error without the `download_dest:` argument?

Comment: @Nakilon It gives no errors if I omit `download_dest: ...`, and `content` variable seems to be a proper instanse of `Google::Apis::DriveV3::File` class. But how do I save files? The `content.web_content_link` gives `nil` (I have changed `response = service.list_files(page_size: 10)` in order not to filter fields, but it doesn't help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error that you got, it says that your request is invalid. So make sure that your request there are correct. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) on how to download files using Ruby(just click the Ruby on the example to view the ruby code.)

> Take NOTE: Downloading the file requires the user to have at least
>   read access. Additionally, your app must be authorized with a
>   [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need)
>   that allows reading of file content.

For more information, check these threads:

- [How to download file from google drive api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874609/how-to-download-file-from-google-drive-api-with-service-account)
- [A Ruby library to read/write files](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby)

Comment: I increased scope to `Google::Apis::DriveV3::AUTH_DRIVE`, but it didn't help. I still have the same error.

Comment: http_command.rb:211 looks like this: `raise Google::Apis::ClientError.new(message, status_code: status, header: header, body: body)`. I had to debug these variables: `status` appears to be `403`, in `header` there is `Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files.` It just happened that I had some google docs files now in the folder, and they threw the error. A very uninformative error. Now it's OK!