# download link for google drive object with service account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm building an api that uses google drive with a service account.

Google Drive objects come with a `@web_view_link` property that looks like:

`"https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9eyEerjltIgZ2dyUTB1eGNjYUk/view?usp=drivesdk"`

When I access this `@web_view_link` in the browser using a **personal account**, the link is functional and the object can be downloaded from there.

When I paste the `@web_view_link` in the browser using a **service account**, Google Drive complains about permissions and I cannot access it, even tho I am accessing with an account owner.

Is it possible to access a download link from google drive using a service account?

I'm using `google-drive-ruby` gem and this is the code to retrieve that `@web_view_link` url:

```
def create_url
  folder_name = Discourse.current_hostname
  found = google_files.select { |f| f.id == id }
  file_title = found.first.title
  file_url = session.collection_by_title(folder_name).file_by_title(file_title).human_url
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service accounts are not your personal accounts. Service accounts [belong to your application](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#background). Make sure you've enabled Drive API when you generated the service account and set the role to owner or editor.

This snippet from [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874609/how-to-download-file-from-google-drive-api-with-service-account) might also help with regard to downloading using service account in ruby:

```
    require 'googleauth'
    require 'google/apis/drive_v2'

    Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2

    upload_source = "/User/my_user_name/hacking.txt"
    drive = Drive::DriveService.new
    # Drive::AUTH_DRIVE is equal to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
    drive.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default([Drive::AUTH_DRIVE])
    file = drive.insert_file({title: 'hacking.txt'}, upload_source: upload_source)
    drive.get_file(file.id, download_dest: '/tmp/my_file.txt')
```

Comment: My question was more: can you access the @web_view_link of an object created with a service account? which this clarifies.. no :) . First downloading to the server and sending *this* link to the user will make the work.